# Simics QSP for RISC-V

Tags: simics

Is there any plans to publish Simics models for other that x86 architectures?
In particular, QSP platforms with ARM-v8 and RISC-V processors?

Any basic platform model (like in QEMU) would be great.

Answer (score 2):

We cannot comment on future unreleased or unannounced products. Unfortunately.

#iamintel